# Convert Separate TableViewController and ViewController into UISplitView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, uisplitviewcontroller

I currently have an iOS application that was originally developer for the iPhone; it was then decided that it was going to be required for the iPad as well. However, there are not many changes to cater for this (only things such as layout, text size and a few others) - the app is just a bigger version for iPad in reality.

One of the things my app makes use of is a UITableView (with a custom UITableCellView). Each one of these then moves onto a UIView. In order to make it a bit more unique to the iPad, I would like to implement a UISplitView to combine these two, to make better use of the larger screen!

This application was handed to me from a previous developer. A large part (95%) of the UI was coded (and not done in Interface Builder). While I am picking up objective-c, there are still some things which throw me. Therefore, my question to you guys is: would this require a huge change in code if I was to combine my UITableView and UIView into a UISplitView? From what I have seen from playing around with the UISplitView, it doesn't seem so. However, because of all the rest being coded, I think the UISplitView will have to be, is that right? Or can I dump in an xib and string up the coded UITableView and UIView?

Final question, is there a tutorial anyone knows about where they have coded a UISplitView? All of them appear to be using Interface Builder.

I hope that is not too much information!

Comment: Please try this link 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6830481/uisplitview-in-uiviewcontroller/10943750#10943750